# Is there a delayed_job like gem for jruby?

Tags: jruby, delayed-job, jrubyonrails

I'm trying to convert a rails app to jruby on rails. Currently, `jruby script/delayed_job run`
gives:

```
/usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.3/lib/delayed/command.rb:50:in `each_object': ObjectSpace is disabled; each_object will only work with Class, pass -X+O to enable (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/lib/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.3/lib/delayed/command.rb:50:in `daemonize'
    from script/delayed_job:5
```

Is there a gem like delayed_job for jruby?

Answer (score 2):

For the record, when deploying to a Servlet container one can use https://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker to run `Delayed::Job` as part of your `JRuby::Rack` application in a separate native (daemon) thread ...

Answer (score 1):

I Wasn't aware the delayed_job used ObjectSpace.
 
Jruby disables it by default and I don't know the performance implications
of enabling it with -x+O.
If you need to process simple and few jobs, you should consider BackgrounDRB.
If you need something to scale, you should check out Workling/Starling.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exactly the same issue. In the end I decided to use Resque instead, which I initially resisted because I thought it would be overkill. You also have another moving part to install, Redis...

However, in the end it turned out to be easy to setup and is very flexible. I'm now really glad I gave it a try.

Comment: Were you using Resque and JRuby on Windows or on a linux or mac?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Fairly standard: Mac for development, Linux for production.

Comment: Thanks for answering, saved me from wasting time trying in vain to get Resque working on Windows Server. Unfortunately, we're tied to a windows server for now.